# How to "prepend" a Char to a String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How in Kotlin can I prepend a `Char` to a `String`?

e.g.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val char = 'H'
  val string = "ello World"
  val appendingWorks = string + char //but not what I want...
  //val prependingFails = char + string //no .plus(str:String) version
  val prependingWorkaround1 = char.toString() + string
  val prependingWorkaround2 = "" + char + string
  val prependingWorkaround3 = String(charArray(char)) + string

}
```

When trying to call `+` (e.g. `plus`) on Char, there is no version that accepts a String on the right, so therefore `'H' + "ello World"` doesn't compile

The first workaround might be good enough but it's a regression for me from what works in Java: `String test = 'H' + "ello World";` (compiles fine...)

I also don't like the last workaround, at least in the `java.lang.String` I have a constructor that accepts a single char, or I can use `java.lang.Character.toString(char c)`. Is there an elegant way in Kotlin to do so?

Was this discussed before (adding a `plus(str:String)` overload to the Char object?)

Comment: Your second workaround looks rather good. The option with string templates suggested in the answers is equivalent and rather concise too. Nevertheless, we should consider adding Char.plus(String) to the standard library. I filed a request about it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4371. Thanks for the report

Comment: @AndreyBreslav this is great, I think `Char.plus(String)` will simply be more consistent with Java and Scala behavior, thanks for listening, Kotlin is getting to be my favorite Scala alternative :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What about using string templates, like this:

```
val prepended = "$char$string"
```

Comment: This language makes me so happy.

Answer (score 4):

As of kotlin 1.5, there is an [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/plus.html) `plus` `operator` function defined on `Char`, which can be used to concatenate a `Char` with given `String`. So you can do

```
val char = 'H'
val string = "ello World"

// Use the function call syntax
val result1 = char.plus(string)

// or use the operator syntax
val result2 = char + string
```

Comment: With the plus operator the warning "Do not concatenate text displayed with `setText`. Use resource string with placeholders." is not shown!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truly prepend a string using just a method call on that string, you can do the following:

```
val str = "ello World!"
println(str.let { 'H' + it })
```

This way can be useful if str was instead a large complicated chain of method calls:

```
val squares = ... // 10x10 array of square numbers
println(squares.joinToString("\n") { 
    it.joinToString(" ") { "%03d".format(it) }
}.let { "Squares:\n" + it })
```